# DML Operations on Custom Object using Custom Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am performing Delete and Update operation on the records in a Visualforce page by fetching the records from an object.

1. Delete operation is working fine but the page is not rendered, I can see the record is deleted only when I refresh the page. Can anybody help me to fix this problem?
2. Update operation is also working fine, and there is the same problem: we have to refresh the page to see the changes.

I have just tried to change the author of record to check whether it is working or not, but my requirement is to get records from the custom object in editable mode, so that i can edit them and then update them?

**Visualforce** page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="fetchingController" id="pageId" >

<!--Fetch data from controller and display on the visual force page  -->
<!-- Here the page looks for a book record in controller -->
<!--Once the controller passes the book record to the page , it uses the dot operator to access the field values in the record and displays them on console  -->
<!-- <b>My Output is Here :</b> <apex:outputText value="The price  of  {!book.name}  is Rupees  {!book.Price__c}"></apex:outputText> -->
<!--Here i will receive the list viz bookList from controller in a PageblockTable  and display its contents in Columns  -->
<apex:form id="formId">
<apex:pageBlock id="pageBlockId1" title="Books Available">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!bookList}" var="bk" id="pageBlockTableId">
   <apex:column headerValue="id">
     <apex:outputText value="{!bk.id}"/>
   </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue=" Name">
<b>  {!bk.Name } </b> 
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Author">
{!bk.Author__c}
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Title">
  {!bk.Title__c} 
  </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Price">
{!bk.Price__c}
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Delete Record">
    <apex:commandLink value="Delete"  action="{!deleteBook}" reRender="pageId">
    <apex:param name="id" value="{!bk.id}"/>
    </apex:commandLink> 
</apex:column>
  <apex:column headerValue="Update Record">
      <apex:commandLink value="Update"  action="{!updateBook}" reRender="pageId">  
    <apex:param name="uid" value="{!bk.id}"/> 
     </apex:commandLink> 
 </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**:

```
public class fetchingController {

    public list<Book__c>  bookList {get;set;}
    public Integer id{get;set;}
    public Integer uid{get;set;}

    public fetchingController(){
           bookList = [Select Id ,Name , author__c , title__c , price__c from Book__c];

    }

// Method to delete Record  
        public PageReference deleteBook() {
                String bookId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
                System.debug('book lsit id is--------------------- '+bookId);
                if (bookId!=''){
                 Book__c book = [Select id from Book__c where id=:bookId ];
                  delete book ;
                }
        return null;
   }

   // Method to update Book Record 

   public PageReference updateBook() {
        String bookUid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uid');
        System.debug('The id for update is ------------------'+bookUid);
        if (bookUid!=''){
        Book__c book =[select Id  from Book__c where id = : bookUid];
            book.Author__c = 'Galvin & Galvin';
        update book;
        }
        return null;
   }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything till now ?
Let us know your progress, share your code, and people will suggest you after that. If you just need a working example, Google it.

Comment: the error that I see immediately is that you don't close your `<apex:pageBlockTable>` tag, but you have two `</apex:pageBlock>` closing tags. Could that be a problem?